# Making a variable in JavaScript from AJAX return Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I scanned a lot of answers here but didn't find a good answer. I'm new to PHP and JavaScript and want to create a variable (for comparison purposes) from a jQuery return value. I'm creating a registration system where I use this to check username availability:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#username").keyup(function (e) {

        //removes spaces from username
        $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\s/g, ''));

        var username = $(this).val();
        if(username.length < 2){$("#user-result").html('');return;}

        if(username.length >= 2){
            $("#user-result").html('<i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i>');
            $.post('core/check_username.php', {'username':username}, function(data) {
             $("#user-result").html(data);
            });
        }
    }); 
});
```

I can display the return value in a span but for form validation purpose, I need to compare this return value with a set of criteria. How can I declare a variable from this return value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `$.post` function you get `data` returned from your ajax-call. just use this to do further stuff with the username:

```
$.post('core/check_username.php', {'username':username}, function(data) {
    $("#user-result").html(data);

    var username = data;

    if(username == "xxx")
    {
        // do some stuff here
    }
});
```